# Prevent overflow by scaling content smaller

Tags: html, css

I want an (animated gif) image in the left top corner. It should never be bigger then the actual size of the image. If the body is to small to show the whole image then the image should be shown smaller, proportional!

I had it working with using a background-image but I want to replay the gif by clicking on it and this didn't work using a background image so I went back to using an image tag.

In the width it works well, however, in the height it does not.

width = good:

[image]

height = not good:

[image]

Here the code:

```
<div id="gifdiv">
    <img src="images/someImg.png"/>
</div>





    body {

        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #gifdiv {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 660px;
        max-height: 370px;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    }
```

Here the code, in case it matters.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#gifdiv").click(function () {
            // first time we replace png to gif
            // after that we just set the same thing again
            // which makes the gif play again from the start            
            var img = $(this).find("img").get(0);  
            var imgSrc = img.src;
            imgSrc = imgSrc.replace(".png", ".gif");
            img.src = imgSrc;     

      });

    });
```

So how can I make the height not exceed the window height?

a fiddle (without a gif)
http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/gLmdwqg8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could be enough :

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Your main problem here is that as your image is 100% width, the height (auto or not) can't be reduced if there is not enough place.

http://jsfiddle.net/gLmdwqg8/1/

Comment: So simple :) aaaaarghhhh